# importing csv file directly into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169562/invalid-field-count-in-csv-input-on-line-1)

When I go to phpmyadmin and after selecting the database and the table which I want when I click on "import". And that when I click on "GO" then it produces the error

> Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1.

So how can I import my csv file directly into mysql database.

I have tried with

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\ah\Documents\mathema_utf8.csv'
    INTO TABLE subject3
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

But it produces the error

> #7890 - Can't find file 'C:UserspratibhaDocumentsmathema_utf8.csv'.

So what should be the name of the file.

Comment: The message you get means that the number of fields on the first line of your CSV does not match the number of columns in the table. Perhaps you can try to specify which columns are present in the file?

Comment: no i have same number of columns.

Comment: @Gordon i have even used that. but that is not working

Comment: Maybe one of the fields in the CSV file contains an unescaped comma?

Comment: @Lex no it doesnt have any unescaped comma. Do, we have to also mention "Fields terminated by" and Fields enclosed by and remaining things while importing.

Comment: @Pratibha Sharma Add to the question `CREATE TABLE subject3` statement and some lines from the CSV-file.

Comment: @Devart CREATE TABLE `quiz`.`subject3` (
`id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`question` VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL ,
`answer` VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL ,
`status` VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
is the creation of table

Comment: before executing `LOAD DATA` , put the file in `<mysql server install path>\bin`.
Please edit the question and provide the table schema details as well as first two lines of the csv.

Comment: See that file it's complaining about in the error?`C:UserspratibhaDocumentsmathema_utf8.csv`. Can you see the difference between that and the file name you supplied? Hint: \ is the escape character in MySQL just like it is in PHP.

Comment: @QuickSilver after changing file url now i have given "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mathema_utf8.csv" now also it is producing the same error

Comment: When i experienced with a similar error `#7890 - Can't find file 'C:UserspratibhaDocumentsmathema_utf8.csv'.` i resolved through the method. `Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1.` is due to the mismatch in csv and table schema. You need to share schema and csv for resolving that.

Comment: @Pratibha Sharma ...and, what about CSV contents? How can we know where error is?

Comment: @Devart my csv file is in excel format. can you provide me your emailid so i can send it to you

Comment: You cannot import data from the Excel file using LOAD DATA INFILE. You said you tried `LOAD DATA FROM mathema_utf8.csv`. I ask you to show some lines from that file.

Comment: @Devart 1 binomialexpression d a
is the content of the csv file(only one row and 4 columns).

Comment: @PratibhaSharma : If the fields are terminated by a space, you need to write `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '` in the command.

Comment: @KhaleelAKarim it worked after giving the space and double slash in address of file

Comment: @PratibhaSharma You should have provided the csv details in the question first :)

Comment: @KhaleelAKarim but now also there is a problem. data goes into the database in one column after the space but i want the column change should take place after the change in cell (in excel)

Answer (score 2):

Do next:

- Field separator -> use ' ' (whitespace), not a comma
- Path separator -> use '\' or '/'

Try this query -

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\ah\\Documents\\mathema_utf8.csv'
INTO TABLE subject3
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Also:

- Possible that line separator should be '\r\n', not '\n'.
- To fix error with path, try to remove LOCAL keyword.

Comment: Accept the answer if it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation once, and for me it was the wrong file encoding.

Try to change the encoding, and also try to specify on the interface.

Another approach is to import to a brand new table, and use SELECT to populate your table.

Comment: i am not clear. can you mention in steps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the mysql server install path as `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0`

Copy the csv file(`mathema_utf8.csv`) into `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\`

and run

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mathema_utf8.csv'
    INTO TABLE subject3
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

This will resolve the second error. But if you want someone to help for the first error you need to provide the schema and details of the csv.

Comment: there is no folder named MYSQL in program files. but there is in xampp\mysql\bin

Comment: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/110129-where-does-xampp-put-the-mysql-server/